# External synchronization on ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, synchronized

The keyword `synchronize` does not appear in the source code of `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Does that mean I am free to use its intrinsic lock for "my own purposes"? Or could this change in the future?

Comment: I couldn't find the class `AbstractBlockingQueue` in JDK6. What's its fully qualified name?

Comment: @Boris: Sorry, that was a mistake. See my updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I'd shy away from it, since *you* could decide to do this, but then someone else on your team or a third party library (perhaps inadvertently) could also rely on having "exclusive" access to the monitor.

It might change in future, and you might not be the only one thinking about this now.  If you can achieve what you want to do using `private` locks and monitors, or via a different system altogether (e.g. executing `Futures`), then that will be more robust.

(It's an interesting question though, and undoubtedly some people will find my opinion too defensive!)